# How to shorten repetitive code regarding lable caption?

Tags: delphi

I have such a code

```
  Label1.Caption := '';
  Label2.Caption := '';
  Label3.Caption := '';
  Label4.Caption := '';
  Label5.Caption := '';
  Label6.Caption := '';
```

How can I make a loop or sth to make it shorter?

Comment: Put the labels in an array and loop over the array

Comment: (1) If they have the same parent and some recognisable property, iterate over the parent's `Controls`. If you find it hard to find a recognisable property, you can use the `Tag`. (2) Put the controls in an array at application startup. (3) If you don't mind writing horribly bad code, you may also use `FindComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make simple procedure to work on array of labels:

```
procedure ClearLabels(LabelsArr: array of TLabel);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
   for i := Low(LabelsArr) to High(LabelsArr) do
      LabelsArr[i].Caption := '';
end;
```

and call it like that:

```
ClearLabels([Label1, Label2, Label3]);
```

Comment: Or with just one more parameter having a default value of `''` make the caption to be assigned variable. A, well... variable.